# Excel 2013: VBA create a range from X number of columns and save as a text file

Tags: vba, excel

So on my "sheet1" I have data in columns A, B, C, D, E, F

I would like VBA code to combine the 1st (A), 3rd(C) and 5th (E) column and save it to a comma separated text file.

I have:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExcelRowsToCSV()

 Dim iPtr As Integer
 Dim sFileName As String
 Dim intFH As Integer
 Dim aRange As Range
 Dim iLastColumn As Integer
 Dim oCell As Range
 Dim iRec As Long

 Dim lenth As String


 Set aRange = Range("A1:C11")

 iLastColumn = aRange.Column + aRange.Columns.Count - 1

 iPtr = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
 sFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, iPtr - 1) & ".txt"
 sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sFileName,  FileFilter:="TXT (Comma delimited) (*.txt), *.txt")
 If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

 Close
 intFH = FreeFile()
 Open sFileName For Output As intFH

 iRec = 0

 For Each oCell In aRange

   If oCell.Column = iLastColumn Then

     Print #intFH, oCell.Value
     iRec = iRec + 1

   Else

     Print #intFH, oCell.Value; ",";
     iRec = iRec + 1

   End If

 Next oCell

 Close intFH

 MsgBox "Finished: " & CStr(iRec) & " records written to " _
 & sFileName & Space(10), vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

This works but only if the range declared has columns that lay right next to each other.

Comment: The line: Set aRange = Range("A1:C10") works and gets the first 3 columns, but if I change it to aRange = Range("A1:A10","C1:C10") and try to capture just the two columns, it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is to copy the worksheet as a new workbook and then delete unnecessary columns and then save the file as csv. This will not affect the original file as well.

For example (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Copy the sheet as a new workbook
    ws.Copy

    ActiveSheet.Range("D:D,B:B,F:F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Sample.Csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close and maybe I am missing something, but the Sample.Csv is a copy of the the original data set and the original data set has those columns deleted. I will play around with it more, but this is brilliant.

Comment: This code needs to be in the module of the original sheet. It will copy the sheet1 from that workbook and create a new workbook where the columns will be deleted. It will not delete the columns from original sheet. I have tried and tested the code.

Comment: Yeah, I put in the wrong location. Works brilliantly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your for each to this: (untested, but hope you get the idea)

```
dim str as string

 For i= 1 to arange.rows
      str=""
      for j=1 to arange.columns

            str=str & ","

      next
      Print #intFH, str
 Next
```